# How to modify activation email content in edX platform?

Tags: azure, activation, edx

I have installed edX platform on Azure and would like to customize the activation email. Would you mind tell me how to modify the activation email content?

I have found several potential files, e.g. /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/emails/activation_email.txt or /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/static/templates/emails/activation_email.txt, ... So I was confused at this point.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can make your content modification in this file:

```
/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/emails/activation_email.txt
```

Subject change:

```
/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/emails/activation_email_subject.txt
```